# Why does Chrome Devtools console do not show variables from my local Scope?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console

I have a problem with my console in Chrome devtool, currently when I trying debug something don't see any of my local scope variables. I'm sure few days ago I didn't have this problem and I saw this.

Currently I see everything in my Local scope but I can't type my variables into a console (below I posted screens).

Maybe was some Chrome update or I change some property - I don't know.

Chrome version: 114.0.5735.91

[raster image of ReferenceError message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6gTH.png)
[raster image of source code in editor window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99Xc.png)

Comment: Is the scope set to "top" or is it targeting an extension or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is set on "top"